# Отступ от края страницы при уменьшении размера браузера

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

**Добрый день!**

При меньшении размера окна браузера появляется не понятный отступ от края страницы. 
Как от него избавиться и как это лечить?

*Начальный дизайн:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*и при уменьшении размера окна браузера:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
 <body>
    <div id="header" class="d-inline-block">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
            <div id="logo">

                <div id="logobox">
                    @ViewBag.Title
                </div>

            </div>
        </a>

        <div id="menu">
            <ul>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="body">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="bodyblock">
            <div class="row-fluid" id="bodyblock">
                <div class="span2" id="sidebar">
                    <div id="navigate">
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home</a></li>
                        <li id="navi" onclick="ulmenuClick();">Configuration</li>
                            <div id="ulmenu">
                                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "ConfigurationURL")">Repository URL</a></li>
                                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "ConfigTFSAccount")">Team Foundation Server Account</a></li>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="bodybar">
                    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix" id="bodybox">
                        @RenderBody()
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Код загрузите куда-нить, тогда и видно будет, что за отступ.

Comment: В первую очередь проверьте, чтобы был css код: html, body {margin:0; padding: 0;}

Answer (score 2):

да вроде нормально всё

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clear,
.clear:after,
.clear:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

html,
body,
.content {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.header-block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: rgba(64, 142, 184, .8);
}

.header-block h2 {
  margin: 0 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.left,
.right {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left {
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #222;
}

.right {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
}

.link-block ul {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.link-block li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 6px;
}

.link-block a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eee;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.right-block {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, .3);
}

.right-block h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
}

.right-block p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.git {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.git input {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 24px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(64, 142, 184, .8), rgba(64, 142, 184, .1));
  margin: 120px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="content clear">
  <div class="header-block">
    <h2>index</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <div class="link-block">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">configuration</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right-block">
      <h2>settings trigger configuration file :</h2>
      <form action="" method="" class="git">
        <p>repository url:</p>
        <input type="" placeholder="Git URL" name="">
        <p>repository login:</p>
        <input type="" placeholder="login" name="">
        <p>repository password:</p>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="">
        <button name="" class="button">send </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```